# Properties of binomial coefficient

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to prove that $$\binom{2n}{n}
=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^2
=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{n-i}\text{.}$$
Okay, I understand, why $\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{n-i}$. For the left-hand side, among $2n$ people, we select $n$ people. On the right-hand side, the committee can consist of $i$ boys and $n-i$ girls, for $i\in\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$. We select $i$ boys and $n-i$ girls for each $i$.

**My Question:** I don't understand how $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^2$ is an equivalent expression. I believe $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^2=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{i}$. How does this equate to the two expressions on either side? Can some give me an intuitive/"story-like" explanation (just like what I did above)?

Comment: You can prove it by expanding $(1+x)^n$ and multiplying it with itself.(the result will be the coefficient of $x^n$ in $$((1+x)^2)^n$$

Comment: It's just the symmetry of the binomial coefficients. Since $\binom{n}i=\binom{n}{n-i}$, it follows $\sum_{i} \binom{n}{i}^2=\sum_i \binom ni\binom{n}{n-i}$. You are replacing one of the copies of $\binom ni$ with $\binom n{n-i}$.

Comment: If you just want an intutition on why $\binom{n}{i}=\binom{n}{n-i}$, then look at Pascal's triangle and go along row $n$ from the left hand side, then from the right hand side. Notice the symmetry of the coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${n \choose i}={n \choose n-i}$ you can prove that by different ways :
one of this ways is as follow:
the number$ {n \choose i}$
is just the number of all northeastern lattice paths from $ O = (0, 0) $ to P =
$(i, n - i)$. Similarly, the number
${n \choose n-i}$ is just the number of all northeastern lattice path from $ O = (0, 0) $ to $P =(n-i, i)$.
These two numbers must
be the same since reflection through the $x = y $ diagonal .

(i invited you to research about northeastern lattice path .it is simple , but it's powerful tool)

so you can put ${n \choose i}^2={n \choose i}.{n \choose i}={n \choose n-i}{n \choose i}$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^2
=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{n-i}\text{}$

simply
because $\binom{n}{n-i}=\binom{n}{i}$